# ¿Cómo hago para incluir los tipos de un archivo .d.ts desde un .js Salsa (typescript)?

Tags: typescript, salsa

Tengo los tipos en un archivo `.d.ts` (porque así lo necesito desde fuera).

```
// example.d.ts
export type Example={
    text: string
    num: number
}
```

Quiero controlar tipos dentro del .js usando JDocs también llamado Salsa

```
/// <reference path="./example.d.ts" />

/** 
  * @type {Example}
  */

var x;
```

Mi `tsconfig.json` indica que deben verificarse los tipos (y lo hace) pero no toma los que están incluidos en el `.d.ts`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true, 
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "checkJs": true
    }
}
```

El mensaje que obtengo es `[js] Cannot find name 'Exampe'.`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### ¿Cómo puedo hacer para incluir los tipos que están en el archivo .d.ts?